# GRASS r.texture :g.proj symbol lookup error

Tags: python, grass-gis, pygrass, grass-7.8

**--Problem Description**
I am trying to use grass within a python code thanks to the grass_session and grass_scirpt packages.

I am not very familiar with the "session" part. From what i understand i need to specify where and how will be named the file architecture my grass functions will work in. I am not sure which one fo GISDBASE/LOCATION... is for me to choose, and which one must point to a specific directory.

As for now my gisbase variable is pointing to where grass 7.8.5 is installed on my computer, that is to say: "usr/lib/grass78"
And i set arbitrary names for "location" and "mapset"

**--The Error**

```
RuntimeError: Cannot create: /home/mambauser/data_agata/grassdata/abancay_peru with the following options: EPSG:32718. Executing:
grass -c EPSG:32718 -e /home/mambauser/data_agata/grassdata/abancay_peru
GRASS said:
b''
b"System locale is not usable (LC_ALL variable not defined). Most likely it indicates misconfigured environment.\nReported error message: unsupported locale setting\nDefault locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.\nStarting GRASS GIS...\nCreating new GRASS GIS location <abancay_peru>...\nERROR: b'g.proj: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.28: undefined symbol: opj_encoder_set_extra_options\n\nExiting...\n"
```

**--Code**

```
class texture:
  
  def __init__(self,filename):
    year=filename[-4:]
    self.path_corona="/home/mambauser/data_agata/"+str(year)+"/Images/"+str(filename)+"/"
    self.path_mask="/home/mambauser/data_agata/"+str(year)+"/Images/"+str(filename)+"/"  +str(filename)
    self.path_mnt='//home/mambauser/data_agata/MNT'
    self.path_indices = "/home/mambauser/data_agata/"+str(year)+"/Indices/"
    

    self.raster_fname=str(filename)
    self.corrected_raster=self.path_corona+str(filename)+'.tif'
    self.used_cores=int(multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2/3)



def haralick_grass(self,filename,bande,nom_bande,fenetre):
    entree= self.corrected_raster
      
    #sortie A changer pour aboutir dans dossier INDICES + ajouter taille radius
    sortie=self.path_indices + str(filename)+'_haralick_{}.tif'.format(fenetre)
    
    #Commebnt gère multibande?
    # settings
    gisbase="/usr/lib/grass78"
    gisdb="/home/mambauser/data_agata/grassdata"
    location="abancay_peru"
    mapset="user_jules"

    rcfile = gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)

    PERMANENT = Session()
     
    PERMANENT.open(gisdb=gisdb, location=location,
                create_opts="EPSG:32718")
     
    PERMANENT.close()
    
    with Session(gisdb=gisdb, location=location, mapset=mapset,
                create_opts="EPSG:32718"):
                 
      #r.texture assumes grey levels ranging from 0 to 255 as inpu
       grass.run_command('r.texture',
               flags="averbose",
               input = entree,
               output = sortie,
             size=fenetre,
              )
    return

fname="corona_30061966"

calcul=texture(fname)
calcul.compute_index(fname)
```

Comment: Might it be possible that you have installed GDAL twice? And GRASS GIS picks up the wrong one?